# Cannot open excel with openpyxl if it contains a chart

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am trying to open an excel file to do some data extraction

```
import openpyxl
import os
book = openpyxl.load_workbook("./file.xlsx")


Traceback (most recent call last):
...
TypeError: expected <class 'openpyxl.chart.axis.NumericAxis'>
```

Checking versions :

```
Version check
$python --version
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda, Inc.

$pip show openpyxl
Name: openpyxl
Version: 3.0.3
Summary: A Python library to read/write Excel 2010 xlsx/xlsm files
Home-page: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io
Author: See AUTHORS
Author-email: charlie.clark@clark-consulting.eu
License: MIT
Location: c:\ .......py3\lib\site-packages
Requires: jdcal, et-xmlfile
Required-by:
```

As best I can tell, it's an Office365 MSO (16.0.11929...) 64 bit version of Excel.

Now the workbook I am trying to manipulate does have charts in it... but I don't want them. I'd be quite happy to open the workbook and delete the sheets that have charts ... but I cannot open the workbook.

Any suggestions?